# How first-fit allocation algorithm reduce memory fragmentation?

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, garbage-collection, ocaml

I'm reading the [Chapter 21 Understanding the Garbage Collector](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/understanding-the-garbage-collector.html) of Real World OCaml.
In the section **Memory Allocation Strategies**, it says:

> **First-fit allocation**
>
> If your program allocates values of many varied sizes, you may sometimes find that your free list becomes fragmented. In this situation, the GC is forced to perform an expensive compaction despite there being free chunks, since none of the chunks alone are big enough to satisfy the request.
>
> First-fit allocation focuses on reducing memory fragmentation (and hence the number of compactions), but at the expense of slower memory allocation. Every allocation scans the free list from the beginning for a suitable free chunk, instead of reusing the most recent heap chunk as the next-fit allocator does.

I can't figure out how first-fit allocation reduces memory fragmentation compare to next-fit allocation, the only different of these two algorithm is they start the searching from different place.

- [Material Design Animation - Jobs allocation First Fit & Best Fit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_cq6pYQe0s)
- [What are the first fit, next fit and best fit algorithms for memory management?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-first-fit-next-fit-and-best-fit-algorithms-for-memory-management)

Comment: Imagine this scenario. You've got `n` free blocks at the start. You allocate one block, then another, then release the first one. You repeat this `n/2` times, so at the end of the process you'll have `n/2` blocks allocated and `n/2` free. With next-fit you'll get them alternating, with first fit, the second half of the heap will be completely empty.

Comment: Of course the flip side of the coin is that with first fit you had to examine roughly `n^2/4` blocks during the process, while with next fit only `n`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the short answer is that Next Fit allocates from blocks throughout the whole free memory region, which means that all blocks are slowly reduced in size. First Fit allocates from as close to the front as possible, so the small blocks concentrate there. Thus the supply of large blocks lasts longer. Since compactions happen where no free block is large enough, First Fit will require fewer compactions.

Answer (score 4):

There is a summary of memory allocation policies and (perhaps) a solution of the memory fragmentation problem for practical programs at http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.97.5185&rep=rep1&type=pdf "The Memory Fragmentation Problem: Solved?" by Johnstone and Wilson. They point out that most work on this problem has been by simulation of memory allocation and deallocation (a point also made by Knuth in Vol 1 Section 2.5). Their contribution is to move from simulation studies based on statistical studies and random number generators to simulation studies based on traces of the memory allocation behaviour of real programs. Under this regime, they find that a variant of best fit tuned for real life behaviour, which uses free lists dedicated to particular memory block sizes for commonly used block sizes, does very well.

So I think your answer is that there is no simple clear answer except for the results of simulation studies, that for common C/C++ programs a variant of best fit can in fact be made to work very well - but if the storage allocation behaviour of OCaml is significantly different from that of C/C++ it is likely that we will only really find out about what is good and bad when somebody runs tests with different allocators using real programs or traces of real programs.

Comment: In the section 2.1.1 of the article you mentioned, it says: "If the block is larger than necessary, it is split and the remainder is put on the free list." Is this what happened in OCaml too?

Comment: I don't know anything specific to OCaml, but it is usual to hand back only what is necessary and to split off the rest and put it on the free list. In fact, you usually start of the system with just one free block, which contains all the available memory. One example of a system which does something different is the Buddy system, which still splits blocks, but only so as to keep all sizes a power of two. This leads to what is called internal fragmentation, where space is wasted because if the user asks for something not a power of two they will be handed a block larger than they requested.